# Creating a SQL batch from a large SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wonder what would be the best approach to run a large T-SQL code about 2500 line in one batch. the code uses about 20 different tables and aggregate data from various data sources, apply business rules and finally insert transform data in a table. The issue I have is the code is too big and every section is relying on the previous result. Should I create one big transaction w rollback? 
should I break the code in multiple smaller stored procedures.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: I would break it up myself.

Comment: The "best" approach is probably to create an agent job. Whether you will split the batch into multiple job steps is totally up to you. Alternatively you can store it in a file and run with `sqlcmd` preferably from the server, as otherwise it will be vulnerable to connection between client machine and server going down and interrupting that batch.

Comment: Whether to run this in a giant transaction or not depends on how much space you have for the log and whether all changes can fit there. If you can take a backup before running the script, and ensure no other changes occur in parallel, you might get away with not using transactions at all. It all depends.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen where a single giant SQL statement works better than piece mealing the logic. And other times where it really needed rewritten into multiple statements.

Personally, I like loading a temp table and inserting/deleting/updating from it until it is the final data to provide. This makes maintenance much easier than a single monolithic SQL statement; maintenance is always concern #1 in my book. If no one can update it without breaking multiple things or it takes ten times longer to implement changes, then it is a bad design. Performance should rarely trump maintenance as the first concern.

Comment: Second that: single large batch may perform better than the same split in smaller batches.